# Java Tile Game Development : Sprite Position Handling

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm developing a small RPG Tile game with Java2D. My Tile creations are done with a 2D array of Strings, converted into corresponding images when drawn. I have a 2D array of Sprites that are to have the same size as my tile array, and it would store which sprites are at which position.

The problem arises when my Monster class contains the position of the monster (X,Y). However, the 2D arraylist of Sprites must correspond to the position of those Monsters.

```
public class Monster {
        private int posX;
        private int posY;
        public Monster (posX, posY){
              this.posX = posX;
              this.posY = posY;
        }
            // setters and getters
        private void Move(){
             this.setPosX (this.getPosX() + 1);
             // would move the monster into posX + 1
        }
```

Then I have in the MonsterSpriteData class:

```
public class MonsterSpriteData{
       private Monster [][] msd;
       public MonsterSpriteData(){
            this.loadMonsterData();
       }

public void loadMonsterData(){
       this.msd = new Monster [size of tile screen X] [size of tile Screen Y]
       //load from text file monster data and set
       msd [loadedMonsterPosY][loadedMonsterPosX] = new Monster (loadedMonsterPosX, loadedMonsterPosY);
       }
```

Then of course, in the main JPanel I call the update() method which moves the position of the Monster. How can I correspond the movement of the monster and store the new position into the msd?

I've tried to store in the Monster class:

```
private void updateMSD(MonsterSpriteData msd, int oldX, int oldY, int newX, int newY){

        msd.getMSD()[newY][newX] = this;
        msd.getMSD()[oldY][oldX] = null;
     }
```

Then call this whenever move() is called in Monster class. But this approach isn't updating it so it matches. Is there any way that I can store the monsters positions more simply?

----------- Edit:
Is this even a good way to handle monster positions? Should I get rid of the X and Y in the Monster class and just handle the position with the 2D array?

Comment: It depends.  If you want more then one thing at a give position on the screen, then some elements will need there own x/y properties.  This will also allow you find things quicker (much easier to run through a short list of values then over the whole 2D array). My personal feeling is you don't really need the second (sprite) array, just away to lookup the required sprite based on the text array

Comment: @MadProgrammer: in the case I do not store my sprites in an array, how would I iterate over them to draw in my main JPanel?

Comment: I'd still have the "text" array, this is what you'd iterator over, you'd then have some lookup mechanism (maybe a `Map`), which would allow to lookup the required sprite associated with the "text value" in the array.  You'd then iterator over the list of "mobile" sprites, determine there x/y positions and draw those, this would allow you to have a "static" and "dynamic" sprites, where the "static" is those things that don't change (much), like the ground or background, and the dynamic sprites which move around and need to be repainted on each cycle

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem thanks to your insight. :)